# Python Counting Inversions through Merge Sort Getting an Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, mergesort, inversion

I'm trying to count the number of inversions in a long text file with Python. I keep getting an error on the line with `left = sortCount(alist, len1, i)`

```
import csv


def mergeCount(alist, i, len1, len2):
    print("Merge")
    inv = 0
    temp = []
    index1 = i
    index2 = i + len1

    while index1 < i + len1 and index2 < i + len1 + len2:
        if alist[index1] <= alist[index2]:
            temp.append(alist[index1])
            index1 += 1
        else:
            temp.append(alist[index2])
            index2 += 1
            inv += i + len1 - index1

    if index2 == i + len1 + len2:
        temp.extend(alist[index1 : i + len1])
    else:
        pass

    write = i
    for value in temp:
        alist[write] = value
        write += 1

    return inv


def sortCount(alist, n, i=0):
    #print("Sort")
    if len(alist) <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        len1 = n // 2
        len2 = n // 2 + n % 2
        left = sortCount(alist, len1, i)
        right = sortCount(alist, len2, i + len1)
        mergeInv = mergeCount(alist, i, len1, len2)

        return left + right + mergeInv

def safeint(val):
   try:
      return int(val)
   except ValueError:
      return val

alist = []

with open('IntegerArray.txt') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')
    for line in lines:
        line = map(safeint, line)
        alist.append(line)

print sortCount(alist, len(alist), 0)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The way you asked the question indicates a deep and fundamental problem with your approach to programming. You did not include the error message. You just said, that an error occurred. Error messages contain information that explain the error. Reading and understanding error messages is a vital pre-requisite for debugging. Please stop ignoring the content of error messages.

Comment: Also try this to analyze your program here [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: I'm using the IDLE Python 2.7 IDE and it isn't giving me a message... I would have written it but I cannot find an error message. It's just in red text

Answer (score 1):

When `len1` becomes `zero`, you are continuously calling `left = sortCount(alist, 0, i)` this same thing again and again.

if `len1==0` return `0`

```
if len1==0:
        return 0

left = sortCount(alist, len1, i)
right = sortCount(alist, len2, i + len1)
```

Modify your `sortCount` like bellow:

```
    def sortCount(alist, n, i=0):
    if len(alist) <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        len1 = n // 2
        len2 = n // 2 + n % 2

        if len1==0:
            return 0

        left = sortCount(alist, len1, i)
        right = sortCount(alist, len2, i + len1)
        mergeInv = mergeCount(alist, i, len1, len2)
    return left + right + mergeInv
```